# Create a related object in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Inventory` related to another model `Product`

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

whenever I create a "Product" I want to create a blank entry of "Inventory" as well.
How can I do that?

Views.py

```
class ProductCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        owner = request.user.pk
        d = request.data.copy()
        d['owner'] = owner
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=d)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("Serializer data", serializer.data)
            Inventory.objects.create(product=serializer.data['id'], quantity = 0, owner = owner)  <= Will this work?
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: use django signals

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is solved by using a signal, however, in this case you will need to add user to the product model like "added_by" to know who added the product and assign inventory owner to that product in your signal. It is not an option, then your request is not possible to implement, because user (owner) is only known in your view and your view will be the only place where you can create the default inventory.

Assuming you added added_by value to your product, your [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/):

```py
@receiver(post_save)
def create_default_product_inventory(sender, instance, created, **__):
    if created and instance.added_by:
        Inventory.objects.create(product=product, owner=instance.added_by)
```

To make it better, instead of the `created` flag, you can check if the product has `added_by` value, but not an inventory item, then create the default inventory item. This will make sure to create a default inventory whenever a user is assigned to a product.

As long as you need the user that created the product to be its inventory owner, you will need to save that user in the product details or just create the related models in the view directly.